# What happens if you don't log out from the site?

Tags: login

When you dont log out from sites,what dangers can occur to your account?Who are the people who can take advantage of this(in evil means)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally depends on the implementation of the site's application. Usually they'll time you out.

Is it possible for someone to do something evil to your account? Again, depends on the implementation. If it was encrypted, chances are no. If it used some way to id your session specific to your browser/computer, probably no. But there could be a bug, someone could intercept things and use a man in the middle attack, etc.

NORMALLY they'll just time out your session after a period of inactivity.

This is assuming you're talking about...a web site? If you're talking games you're probably on the wrong forum.

Comment: I am talking about websites,like fb,yahoo,hotmail.Why is there a need to sign out?

Comment: It explicitly closes your connection and transactions, it offers a sense of security to people, and if you're on a computer at home where most users tend to be lazy, it keeps your kid sister from coming over and emailing naughty messages to your friends. It also depends (again!) on the IMPLEMENTATION of the application in question, as on some systems when you sign out the application may do something such as emptying the trash, while just closing out can lead to never executing those commands. It also may close open IP connections.

Comment: Most of these answers depend on the implementation of the application. Sites like Amazon never really seem to care about whether you're fully signed out. Others like facebook push updates to your browser every few minutes.